# How do I normalize a matplotlib colorbar to a scalar array between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have a .jpg image of a colorbar which was generated with matplotlib:

[image: Colorbar]

I would like to linearly assign a float to the scale so that it ranges from 0 to 1. That is, the left most colors (purple) would represent values close to zero, and the right most (red) would represent values approaching one.

My initial idea used PIL in python to convert to greyscale, and then normalize that array. The code I used is:

```
from PIL import Image

bar = Image.open('colorbar.png')
bar_gs = bar.convert(mode='L')
gs_values = np.zeros(bar_gs.size[1])

for i in range(0, bar_gs.size[1]):
    gs_values[i] = pix_gs[00,i]
```

This creates a greyscale version of the colorbar which looks like:

[image: Greyscale ColorBar]

Plotting a single row of this gives:

[image: Plot]

The sharp dips are obviously the tick marks. The real issue is that this is not a monotonically increasing/decreasing function like I had hoped. I need to have a single y-axis value for a given x value. Because there are multiple humps in the third plot, that's not the case.

So it seems that I'm actually losing information by converting to greyscale. My end goal is to be able to assign some color a value between 0 and 1. Is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to read about [why 'jet' should be avoided](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I think that perfectly describes why I'm having trouble.